# exposing the inner methods of a class, and using them

Tags: python, python-2.7

Let's say I have a class like so:

```
class Shell:
  def cat(self, file):
    try:
      with open(file, 'r') as f:
        print f.read()
     except IOError:
      raise IOError('invalid file location: {}'.format(f))
   def echo(self, message):
     print message
   def ls(self, path):
     print os.listdir(path)
```

In a javascript context, you might be able to do something like `"Class"[method_name]()`, depending on how things were structured. I am looking for something similar in python to make this a "simulated operating system". EG:

```
import os
def runShell(user_name):
  user_input = None
  shell = Shell()
  while(user_input != 'exit' or user_input != 'quit'):
    user_input = raw_input('$'+ user_name + ': ')
    ...
```

now, the idea is they can type in something like this...

```
$crow: cat ../my_text
```

... and behind the scenes, we get this:

```
shell.cat('../my_text')
```

Similarly, I would like to be able to print all method definitions that exist within that class when they type `help`. EG:

```
$crow: help\n
> cat (file)
> echo (message)
> ls (path)
```

is such a thing achievable in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in function [`vars`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) to expose all the members of an object. That's maybe the simplest way to list those for your users. If you're only planning to print to `stdout`, you could also just call `help(shell)`, which will print your class members along with docstrings and so on. `help` is really only intended for the interactive interpreter, though, so you'd likely be better off writing your own help-outputter using `vars` and the `__doc__` attribute that's magically added to objects with docstrings. For example:

```
class Shell(object):
    def m(self):
        '''Docstring of C#m.'''
        return 1
    def t(self, a):
        '''Docstring of C#t'''
        return 2

for name, obj in dict(vars(Shell)).items():
    if not name.startswith('__'): #filter builtins
        print(name, '::', obj.__doc__)
```

---

To pick out and execute a particular method of your object, you can use [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr), which grabs an attribute (if it exists) from an object, by name. For example, to select and run a simple function with no arguments:

```
fname = raw_input()
if hasattr(shell, fname):
    func = getattr(shell, fname)
    result = func()
else:
    print('That function is not defined.')
```

Of course you could first tokenize the user input to pass arguments to your function as needed, like for your `cat` example:

```
user_input = raw_input().split() # tokenize
fname, *args = user_input #This use of *args syntax is not available prior to Py3
if hasattr(shell, fname):
    func = getattr(shell, fname)
    result = func(*args) #The *args syntax here is available back to at least 2.6
else:
    print('That function is not defined.')
```